# Configuring Require js to load AMD modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js, amd

I am new with writing test cases for testing my javascript files using gulp, mocha, chai.

My file directory

```
Project
|-- _src
|   `-- scripts
|       `-- ui
|           |-- ChangePos.js
|           |-- PosRenderer
|           `-- utils
|               |-- Element
|               `-- Config
`-- test
    `-- index.js
```

utils/**ChangePos.js**

```
 define(['Config',
            'Element',
            'PosRenderer'

] {
      function() {
      //mycode
      }
    });
```

It has dependency on Config and Element files.

test/index.js

```
var requirejs = require("requirejs");
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './../_src/scripts/ui',
    paths: {
        utils: 'utils'
    },

    nodeRequire: require,
    map: {
        '*': {
            'NIT.Cookie': 'utils/Element'
        }
    }
});

    describe('almeObjectConfig', function() {
        var ele, conf, obj;
        before(function (done) {
            requirejs(['utils/Config', 'utils/Element'],
                function (config, element) {
                    console.log('Configuration: ' + config);
                    console.log('Element: ' + element);
                ele = element;
                conf = config;
                done();
            });
        });
```

I am trying to load **ChangePos** which has dependency on **Element** and **Config** by specifying path 'utils'.

```
utils: 'utils'
```

I can load Element explicitly by specifying baseURL as `baseUrl:'./../_src/scripts/ui/utils'` but here it is checking only inside ui folder and giving an undefined object.

It works if I put all files in **ui** folder as it is considering the base URL and looking only inside the base folder.

I am not sure what am I missing here. 
Thanks for the help inadvance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your configuration I see nothing that would allow `ChangePos` to load `utils/Element` as `Element` and `utils/Config` as `Config`. In particular, the `paths` configuration `'utils': 'utils'` does not do this, and does nothing at all with the specific configuration you have. To get the code you have to work, you'd have to have `paths` be:

```
paths: {
    'Config': 'utils/Config',
    'Element': 'utils/Element'
}
```